# Difference between TabHost and FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-tabs, fragment-tab-host

I have the following tutorials on creating tabs in Android. It is found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html) and [here](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/).

The first one uses FragmentTabHost and the second one uses TabHost in creating the tab with the use of fragments. I have a difficulty in trying to identify its difference and implication on its performance.

I tried to search but failed to find the answer. Can anyone help me here? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I know that FragmentTabHost extends TabHost but I want to know other information that might be beneficial, i.e. which is better and what could be the possible performance issues that a developer can see in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a difficulty in trying to identify its difference and
>   implication on its performance.

As it's name suggest a `FragmentTabHost` is a special case of `TabHost` **specifically built** to handle tab fragments. As you can see from the official guide it's quite easy to use the `FragmentTabHost` with fragments, compare this to the tutorial that you linked to and you'll see the(quite big) difference(which makes it easier to make errors).

There isn't a performance difference other than a performance problem introduced by working with the fragments themselves(which shouldn't happen if they are built right).

It's kind of the same difference between an `Activity` and a `ListActivity`, one(the `ListActivity`) *makes it easier to work* in a specific scenario(content using a `ListView`) through some convenience methods(`getListView()`, `getListAdapter()` etc).

Comment: Appreciated this idea. Will use FragmentTabHost then. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but FragmentTabHost relies on android.support.v4, which many apps targeting Ice Cream Sandwich and above do not include.